# How do authentication servers handle thousands of CPU intensive logins?

Tags: authentication, bcrypt

Apologies if the answer is obvious, I'm just a little curious and couldn't nail down an answer elsewhere.

I'm used to seeing authentication servers use simple SHA-1 or SHA-256 to validate credentials, but best-practise these days is normally to use bcrypt for credential hashing.

The problem is that bcrypt is designed to use significant amounts of CPU and/or memory to limit the efficacy of brute-forcing algorithms. Easy for a single logon, but when hundreds or thousands of logons are involved, do server admins just throw extreme amounts of hardware at the problem, or do they tweak the bcrypt parameters to ensure a reasonable logon time for users?

Comment: This is such a small and hardly noticeable part of the CPU usage of a web server!

Comment: @MichaelHampton hmm, if that is true, I would argue that you're doing it wrong. A trivial amount of CPU usage means the credential hashing (and therefore password recovery) is susceptible to brute force attacks.

Comment: No, it's such a small part because the majority of the CPU is being used by your web application!

Answer (score 1):

You <strike>can't</strike> shouldn't be tweaking the bcrypt parameters too low. The parameters **should** be set so that it takes *at least* ~250 ms to verify a password.

That means you **will** be consuming 100% of a CPU core for 250 ms each login.

So:

- on a single core, you can only login 4 people a second
- on dual core: 8 people a second
- quad core: 16 people a second

Fortunately once someone logs in, you will hand them back an **authentication cookie**. If you do it right, and the authentication cookie doesn't expire for 50+ years, you'll never have to verify their password again.